# CSS: Could not override inherited text-decoration property

Tags: html, css

I'm going to use such CSS table for my menu:

```
.menu {text-decoration:underline;}
.menu a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#0202C0}
.menu a:active {text-decoration:none; color:#0202C0}
.menu a:visited {text-decoration:none; color:#0202C0}
.menu a:hover {text-decoration:underline; color:#0099FF}
```

but while trying to apply it to the document

```
<span class="menu">
   Some underlined text came here... 
   <a href="...">this text should not be underlined until mouse on!</a>
</span>
```

I found unexpected behavior: link text always stay underlined. What I'm doing wrong? Could it depends on browser (I'm using Mozilla Firefox 3.5.6, probably IE 6.0 display it properly)? If so, how can I rely CSS at all? What should I use to substitute it?

(In fact usually I got learned new programming languages very quickly and never had any problems with programing basis until I started HTML and CSS. Either I'm incompatible with it or its features was never recounted well enough.)

Comment: Remove `.menu { text-decoration:underline }`.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not you: CSS is a cruel mistress.

Comment: A quick play reveals that this _may_ be an oddity of Firefox. Certainly in the only other browser I have here (IE6!) your code comes out as you would expect.
Also, Firebug suggests that according to the Firefox DOM, the link has "text-decoration: none", which isn't the case visually.

Comment: icabod, yeah, it looks so... But it shows a particular (very) big problem of browser incompatibility... Sp the question turn into: 'how should I debug my site to be watched properly at most of browsers including my?' lol.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it again, you may find that the link indeed _isn't_ underlined... but the entire span that surrounds it is, hence the link looks underlined. For example if you put a border around the span, but no border around the link, your span's border would expand to encase the link also.

That may explain what you're seeing. In which case you'd need to find some other solution, such as my suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick play with some CSS, a workaround (which is *horrid*, but does work) would be to do the following in your CSS:

```
.menu span {text-decoration:underline;}
```

... in place of the first line of your sample CSS.
Then in the HTML do the following:

```
<span class="menu">
    <span>Some underlined text came here...</span>
    <a href="...">this text should not be underlined until mouse on!</a>
    <span>Some more underlined text came here...</span>
</span>
```

It's far from being perfect, but is the best I can come up with for the moment.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, it work as I told before in the answer to  Ipsquiggle's comment of slebetman's answer. It is solution, but it is partial, such strange behavior could happen any time. Moral: never swap understanding of default and emphasized text's from standard meaning in html formatting. It is not LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding:

```
.menu a {text-decoration:none}
```

before all the other rules? Just to establish a default which is then overridden by the `a:hover` rule.

Comment: What about trying this in other cases? Add a `<span>` within the menu span, and then try `.menu span {text-decoration:none;}`. If that doesn't work, there may be a larger issue.

Comment: This is strange. It should work. Are you sure there are no other css rules interfering?

Comment: I tried, it worked if inside .menu span with .menu span {text-decoration:none} I put other text into inner span with {text-decoration:underline}. Thank you, in fact I supposed so... Just I wish to know how to override inherited property.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that it is a valid link inside of the href. If you do not supply this style:

```
.menu a, .menu a:link{my styles}
```

and the `href` has no contents, some browsers will not treat it as a link and do default text rendering. For example, `<a href="">` will not take on the style of `.menu a:link`, it will go to the default `.menu` styles because there is no link and it is not rendered as such by some browsers.

Of course, cover your bases by including the bare `a` in your selector.

Additionally, make sure you end those color styles with semicolons for proper CSS syntax.

Comment: It has proper link inside... Even if have no any link my Firefox still apply color properly and change it when mouse on, only underline could not be removed.

Comment: Are you applying underlines elsewhere in the document? Perhaps it is inheriting from something else, and .menu and .menu a is insufficient to override it. Google CSS Specificity to understand further - nice tutorial here http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Oh, no, I do not underlining anything else, I cleaned the example exactly as you see it in question.

Comment: You're right, I've never seen this before. It occurred in IE for me as well. The solution by icabod may be your best bet. I'd +1 your question if I had a better reputation, this is crazy!

Comment: @neatlysliced thanks for the link to the CSS-TRICKS article... that has just solved a ton of annoying problems for me

Answer (score -1):

To the text you want to underline, use `<u>blabla</u>` (do it the HTML way).
This won't inherit and your next link won't come out underlined.

Comment: it did not show on the answer I just posted but my point is that, you should underline using the letters "u" around the text. Use HTML sometimes instead of CSS