# How to underline on hover text within element that excludes a child element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Code is as follows:

```
<h1 class="slide-title">
<span class="slider-category">
<a href="/test/test.html"> Blocking irritating text</a>
</span>
Hong Kong Trip Nov 2015 – Day 3 Itinerary
</h1>
```

Using `h1.slide-title:hover` will affect the "Blocking irritating  text" within the span element as well.

I **ONLY** want to underline on hover the following text "Hong Kong Trip Nov 2015 – Day 3 Itinerary", I **DO NOT** want the "Blocking irritating text" to be underlined when I hover over it.

Is this possible with CSS or jQuery?

Edit: question is not duplicate as I do not want to edit the HTML. Also as a side note, I would like the `<span>` element to underline on hover separately as well.

Comment: Can you change the HTML?

Comment: Well if I could easily I wouldn't be asking here. I could use jQuery to change the HTML. Wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Was a simple question...no need to be snippy.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't mean to come across as snippy :(

Comment: How are you underlining...with `text-decoration`?

Comment: Yes, that's the intention, but if there's another way that can achieve the intended effect I'm open to it

Comment: The problem David is that you cant target text that doesnt have an element to target. Using jQuery you could wrap the text into a span element with an associated class.

Comment: Then no...that's not the way `text-decoration` works..it applies to the whole block element. I'd use Jquery to parse the text after the `span` and underline it some other way...or just wrap  that in the `span` and style accordingly.

Comment: does this work for u https://jsfiddle.net/0jk1meyd/2/?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element?lq=1

Comment: Yep I'm aware, was hoping that there is another way. Have too many funky jQuery scripts on my site as it is lol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Could not override inherited text-decoration property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111100/css-could-not-override-inherited-text-decoration-property)

Comment: @Sushil wow great answer! unfortunately I also want the <span> element to underline when hovered on, separately

Comment: oh. let me see if i can do something with that.

Comment: @DavidZ I totaly changed my answer, have a look

Comment: @Sushil the Fiddle does not work for me :/

Comment: Sushil got there first with that answer, fyi :)

Comment: @DavidZ the same? his fiddle link show nothing like that (or working) to me

Comment: @CodeiSir fair enough - as I've said above ti Sushil as a follow-up, unfortunately I also need the <span> element to underline when hovered on, separately

Comment: @DavidZ did you see my anwer? You don't need extra stuff it's possible in CSS

Comment: @CodeiSir yep, hope you didn't miss my comment above too :)

Comment: @DavidZ I still can't find a solution in the comments

Comment: @CodeiSir I gave your ans an upvote but as stated, I need the "Blocking irritating text" to underline on hover separately as well, currently looking at jQuery solutions to wrap the text around with a <span> tag

Comment: I am still working on it.

Comment: @DavidZ a now I understand, well that's easy I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.slide-title a {text-decoration:none;}
.slide-title a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}

$("h1.slide-title").each(function(){
    $(this).contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType === 3 /*text node*/) {
      $(this).wrap("<a></a>");
    }
  });
});
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvn43ncg/1/

Comment: I used `<a></a>` as a wrapper for simplicity, but you could use any element/class and then add to the CSS accordingly.

Comment: Its an easy fix, but your version doesnt underline when he hovers on the entire h1 element as his original requested.

Comment: Also if he has many i would run .each() to do it for everyone of them.

Comment: Could someone edit the answer to include the .each()? I have quite a few

Comment: Anyways I couldn't get this code to work on my site for some reason - it didn't add the tags that I selected - and it also broke some other functions that I needed

Comment: could you provide a link to your site?  I can add the .each() - one sec.

Comment: Just updated the code and the fiddle.  I'll take a look at your site.

Comment: actually getting very close to the solution, I couldn't use insertBefore, etc because they were many tags of the same class and it would basically insert ALL the tags rather than just the one after it

Comment: @andi looks like your code is conflicting with an existing jQuery script, not too sure how or why... any work arounds? love the idea though

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the error console, to give a clue?

Comment: No errors, I have your code live on the site and I've purged caches, do a hard refresh and take a look yourself :) slider is totally messed up lol, and <span> tag not inserted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100185/discussion-between-andi-and-david-z).

Comment: if you add a class to the inserted tag, remember to use a single ' instead, using " broke it

Answer (score 7):

You will have to change the Element you don't want to be affected by `text-decoration` a little with `display: inline-block`:

```css
h1.slide-title:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h1.slide-title a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1.slide-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="slide-title">
  <span class="slider-category">
    <a href="/test/test.html">Blocking irritating text</a>
  </span>
  Hong Kong Trip Nov 2015 – Day 3 Itinerary
</h1>
```

[[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props)] Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

So you could also use `float: left` or `position: absolute`

Comment: very close, but if you put it in a fiddle and play around with it you'll see the problem

Comment: intention was for the "blocking irritating text' to underline on hover separately, here when you hover over it, the whole text gets underline - doesn't look like I can get it done with CSS :(

Comment: oh yeah. you're right. thats the issue even I am facing

Comment: @DavidZ its realy hard to get what you mean. but i understand. I know how to solve it, by I have no time right now

Comment: @CodeiSir sorry about that, well if you can solve it with pure CSS you're really pretty good at this

Comment: @DavidZ as far as i know it should not be possible in css3 but in css4. bin with JS its easy

Comment: @CodeiSir I'm actually having a ton of trouble just trying to add <span> tags around the unwrapped text using jQuery - for one, there are multiple instances of the element with the class, so insertBefore or insertAfter won't work... another solution below conflicted with another script

Comment: @DavidZ loop through the nodes of the element, check if its a text node (`.nodeType` === 3) and if it's not a blank node (.trim() on its content and check if its not empty) and then wrap this in the new span

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy way that works is to run a jQuery code such as this.

```
$('.slide-title').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).find(".slider-category").html();
  $(this).find("span").remove();
  var ex = $(this).text();
  $(this).empty();

  $(txt+"<span class='extra-txt'>"+ex+"</span>").appendTo(this);
});
```

Add CSS such as

```
h1.slide-title:hover .extra-txt {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1.slide-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1.slide-title:hover a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Here is a working version.

https://jsfiddle.net/mjtmtsa5/3/

Comment: Could you modify your code to simply insert the span tags to the unwrapped text and leave the original span tag alone?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$('h1').hover(function()
{
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {  
    return this.nodeType == 3 ? $(this).wrap('<u></u>') : null;  // nodeType == 3 returns the inner text of the target element
  });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/bvtngh57/151/

Comment: Doesnt meet to his request.

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't ?

Comment: Doesnt hover, its syntaclly incorrect, and it will effect all h1.. -1